# Having problems setting a key binding in Emacs "general.el" pacakage

Tags: key-bindings

I am using this https://github.com/noctuid/general.el to set my various key bindings. Here is a demonstration of a problem I am having:

```
(general-nmap haskell-mode-map "<leader>t" 'foo-bar)
(general-nmap "<leader>td" 'my-rg-todo)
```

The second line causes the following error:

```
error: Key sequence <leader> t d starts with non-prefix key <leader> t
```

Why is the problem and what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound a function to `<leader> t`, and then tried to bind another function to `<leader> t d`. But that key sequence can never be activated because `<leader> t` would be called first, leaving just an ordinary `d` to do whatever `d` is bound to.

You need to change one key binding or the other, so that either `<leader> t` is not used as a prefix for other keys, or so that it is left free to be a prefix.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you. Your answer got me on the right path with new keywords to search for and I eventually found my solution in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1fgypEiQkE.